# Nested Shortcodes?

Tags: wordpress, nested, shortcode, podscms

For my WordPress site, I am using both PODS, and WPDataTables to manage my data. With that, I am using WPDT's "placeholder" feature to create dynamic SQL queries that will display different data depending on what user is logged in. Currently, I can ALMOST do everything I need, but not quite. This is more or less what I would like to achieve ***(var1 = the output of another shortcode)***:

```
[wpdatatable id=14 var1= 
[pods name="User" template="Company" where="id = {@user.id}"][/pod]]
[/wpdatatable]
```

This shortcode is working, and will pull back a single number, based on the user that is logged in:

```
Company: [pods name="User" template="Company" where="id = {@user.id}"]
```

And this code is working if I hardcode a specific value to var1:

```
[wpdatatable id=14 var1=5]
```

Basically, I have two separate shortcodes that work individually, but will not work when put together. I was wondering if something like this would be possible? Or if I needed to maybe think of a new approach. Thanks in advance!

Side Note: I have tried using the "*Outerbridge Nested Shortcodes*" plug-in without any luck. After talking with the plug-in author, I discovered that this plugin only works for:

```
[tag-a] [tag-b] [/tag-a]
```

And not:

```
[tag-a [tag-b] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

That's something wpdatatable needs to enable like we do it for pods but that would be around the other way see how it's done for pods: https://pods.io/docs/build/using-shortcodes-pods-templates/